# How can guard route on server after async fetch

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering

I have tried to guard a specific route same as a global route on server as well as on client.
All the data is fetching after all routes execute guard hook. I can exec `beforeResolve` in `onReady` on client side and reject route if I need it after fetching data.

As example… I need to fetch all the data in a route and if a property is greater in this data then value then I will redirect (by next) to another route.
I can do this on the client side. How can I do this on server side if all guard hooks are resolved before fetching data?
Please see my code below `server-entry.js`:

```
export default context => {
  return app({cookies: context.cookie})
    .then(({app, router, store}) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         router.push(context.url);
        router.onReady(() => {
          const matchedComponents = router.getMatchedComponents();
          if (!matchedComponents.length) {
            return reject({code: 404})
          }
          Promise.all(matchedComponents.map(Component => {
            if (Component.asyncData) {
              return Component.asyncData({
                store,
                route: router.currentRoute
              })
            }
          })).then(() => {
            context.state = store.getState();
            context.meta = app.$meta();
            resolve(app)
          }).catch(reject)
        }, reject)
      })
    })
}
```

On documentation on vue exist example for prefetch for client-side. but not exist for server-side.
I will really appreciate your help.